# .Net Core Web API Swagger No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost/swagger

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, webapi

I'm working on .NET core web API and I wanted to integrate the project with Swagger.

I have followed all the steps in this article
https://dev.to/amoenus/how-to-integrate-swagger-ui-in-a-net-core-web-api-application-amoenus-dev-13o1

Now the project is not running on IIS , So to navigate to swagger I typed http://localhost:8080/swagger.

Because I have this in `StartUp`

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API");
            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        });
```

And honestly I assumed the port is 8080 because I don't know what is my port.

Can someone tell me if I can have swagger if i'm not running on IIS and how to know exactly my localhost port?

Answer (score 1):

Settings are in `launchSettings.json` and it is under Properties folder in web api root. Below is sample from my settings.

```
"profiles": {
    "test-web-api": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "local"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "local"
      },
      "use64Bit": true
    }
  }
```